# How can i make 2 attributes unique in a table (Django)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

It is possible to have a unique row, and make create_or_update on it?
image: [image]

I want to have unique attributes for idTest + EmailStudent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a **`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc] to your model class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    idtest = models.IntegerField()
    emailstudent = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['idtest', 'emailstudent'],
                name='unique_idtest_emailstudent'
            )
        ]
```

As for [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create) you use the two uniqueness objects as kwargs, and the other that you want to specify when creating/updating in the `defaults=…` parameter:

```
MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
    idtest=my_id_test,
    emailstudent=my_emailstudent,
    defaults={'otherfield': some_value}
)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added this and i used TestStudent.objects.update_or_create to update_or_create object on DB. but don't working (don't make update on object).

Comment: Hmm, not working. i think i make something wrong.            `newStudentUpload = TestStudent.objects.update_or_create(
                file=request.FILES['file'],
                defaults={'idTest': testInfo, 'emailStudent': request.user, 'file': request.FILES['file']}
            )`

Comment: @NicolaeElisei: you should remove the `file=request.FILES...` from the kwargs, this belongs to the `defaults`. the `idTest` and `emailStudent` on the other hand do *not* belong in the `defaults` but in the kwargs.

Comment: Working. Thanks very much @Willem Van Onsem